# Putting CreateElementNS in a function (SVG Groups, shapes etc)

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to turn this code right here:

```js
var group = function(n){
 n = document.createElementNS(svg, "g" );
}
```

Am I doing it right? I have also tried with 'Return n = doc...' but that doesn't seem to work either.

At the moment I just have allot of lines like this;

```js
e.g1 = document.createElementNS(svg, "g" );
 t2 = "translate("+e.x+" "+e.y+"), rotate("+e.z+" "+0+" "+0+")";
 e.g1.setAttributeNS(null, "transform", t2);
 e.g1.setAttributeNS(null,"fill", "url(#gradient)"); 
 e.g1.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke", "none");
 e.g1.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-width", e.a*0.03);
 document.getElementById("mySVG").appendChild(e.g1);
```

Would prefer it to look more like this..

```js
    group(e.g1);
 t2 = "translate("+e.x+" "+e.y+"), rotate("+e.z+" "+0+" "+0+")";
 transform(e.g1, t2);
 fill(e.g1, url(#gradient));
 stroke(e.g1, #000);
 strokewidth(e.g1, (e.a*0.03));
    append(e.g1);
```

Thanks, shorter code is what I need!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that won't work.  When you do:

```
var group = function(n){
    n = document.createElementNS(svg, "g" );
}
```

You are just modifying the value of n that gets passed in.  The changes are purely local to the function and don't make it back out to the caller.

You will need to do:

```
var group = function() {
    return document.createElementNS(svg, "g" );
}

e.g1 = group();
```

Or, I suppose you could do:

```
var group = function(obj, property){
    obj[property] = document.createElementNS(svg, "g" );
}

group(e, 'g1');
```

But I'm not sure why you'd want to do it that way :)

Comment: Thanks mate,

I am going in way too deep for my skill level but progressing fast thanks to people like you.